# How can I count cars in an image with Google Cloud Vision API?

Tags: python, google-cloud-vision

I need a count of all the **cars** included in a image with the Google Cloud Vision API in Python.
 I take only the labels of the image right now.

```
import io
import os
from google.cloud import vision
from google.cloud.vision import types
client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();
file_name = os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__file__),
    'car.jpg');
with io.open(file_name,'rb') as image_file:
    content = image_file.read();
image = types.Image(content=content)
response = client.label_detection(image=image)
print(response)
```

Comment: Use any JSON parser and filter the label 'CAR'

Comment: Yes, but cloud vision only response one label for all objects, Example one label of car.

Answer (score 1):

Label detection will detects a set of categories that are proper to the picture as explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-labels). I don't think it could be used to count cars since it will return some related labels (e.g car, motor vehicle, city car...) for all the cars but without specifying the number of cars. So same label could be returned for 3, 5 or other number of cars.